# pointer value not changing together?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
  int* a = NULL;
  int* b = a;
  b = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
  *b = 10;
  printf("%d, %d", *a, *b);
  return 0;
}
```

With the code above, I found that although I change the value that b dereferences, the value that a dereferences does not change. Can someone explains why? I thought they should change together.

Comment: They are not associated. Anyway, `b` was given the value of `a` and then overwritten by the return value from `malloc`.

Comment: a points to null, you assign a to b, now b points to null also, you point b to some memory you allocate then change the value stored there, a still points to null.

Comment: Oh yeah that makes sense.

Comment: [Do not cast `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) and don't forget to check if `malloc` returns `NULL` and to free the requested memory with `free(b)`.

Answer (score 2):

After `b = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));`, `b` points to the block of memory you just allocated and `a` still contains `NULL`.
When you do `*b = 10;` you store a 10 in the block of memory you allocated. Still, `a` doesn't point to anything.

Since `a` is never made to point to anything, the `*a` in the `printf` doesn't make any sense.